Cannot GET / on page refresh with express
I'm running a little MERN stack project. I was able to deploy it on Vercel and get it to run. I can use the buttons in the browser to get to "/classes" and "/students", however when I reload on either of those pages, it says it cannot GET "/classes" or "/student"
This is the server backend
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const classRoutes = require('./routes/classRoutes')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
});

app.use('/api', classRoutes)

const atlasConnectionUri = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(atlasConnectionUri, {
    dbName: 'subjects'
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is Running at ${PORT}`);
});

This is the App.jsx on frontend
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CoursePage from "./pages/CoursePage";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import "./App.css";
import StudentPage from "./pages/StudentPage";

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>

      <h1>MERN Stack Classes App</h1>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Home />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/classes"
          element={<CoursePage />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/students"
          element={<StudentPage />}
        />
      </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App

This is my folder structure for reference

I searched and from what I read, I'm not serving up my HTML as default for redirect. So I tried adding a redirect to HTML file using
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

But when i reload the domain, it says INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Can you add the Internal Server Error stack-trace? The error should show up on the console.

Console says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

You need the output from the console you spawned the code from. The NodeJS backend console not the browser console. That will hint you on the possible problems.

To start a FullStack MERN app you need to serve frontend built at the fallback route.
i.e.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

But for this, you need to build the frontend first. npm run build will create a dist folder inside your frontend folder. Now you can serve these files.
Assuming the fallback route is defined in index.js file. The relative path for the dist will be ../frontend/dist hence the fallback route should be.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist', 'index.html'));
});

Now all the routes not defined in express will be redirected to the frontend.

I tried that. My dist folder is in my backend. So its..
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist', 'index.html'));
});

But it still did not work.

What are you getting on console? also try ./dist
